# How can I find the distance between rows using the longitude and latitude columns using MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, latitude-longitude, haversine

I have a database with lng and lat columns for each row. How can I make a SQL query that will return the rows in order of the distance? I will compare the lat and lng with external values. I will send the SQL query with PyMySQL using Python. If this isn't possible, I have the haversine formula written in Python, and I can calculate the distances like that, but I don't want to have to waste time looping through all the entries in the database, which is very big.

Sample Table:

```
   long ============ lat
============================
1. -74 ============= 84
2. -87 ============= 75
```

What I expect to happen. I give a long, lat coordinate and it compares it to all the rows in the database, and it returns the rows in order of the closest to the farthest to the coordinate I provide.

Comment: in order of distance from what? please show some sample code so people can help accordingly

Comment: It would be great if you can provide us with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Might be interesting to read: https://mysqlserverteam.com/geography-in-mysql-8-0/

Comment: @Paolo Did that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to include a calculated field column for the distance.  Your ORDER BY would use the calculated field.

Comment: Not necessarily. The distance can be computed on the fly.

Comment: @TheImpaler I was planning that. I will append the top 5 rows in order to a list of distances.

Comment: Your comment means that you could do a top 5 based on the calculation.  Your initial post made me think that you would want all of the calculated distances.

Comment: @Hopper Both are true. I will want all the distances, yet in Python, I will append the top five to a list. The other distances I will use as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would implement the Haversine function as a MySQL function, as in:

```
create function haversine_distance (
  float long1, 
  float lat1,
  float long2,
  float lat2)
returns float deterministic
return ... -- formula here
```

Once you have that, then the query becomes really simple. For example for longitude `10.21` / latitude `-50.45`, the query would look like:

```
select *
from my_table
order by haversine_distance(long, lat, 10.21, -50.45) asc
```

Comment: I am not good at MySQL, and that it is not my intention to learn this moment. I will run the SQL query with either PyMySQL or phpmyadmin. Is there a way you might be able to explain some of the unusual code?

Comment: Well, the first part is the definition of a formula (the Haversine formula you mentioned) in the MySQL engine (manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html). The second part is as simple SQL that retrieves the rows sorted by the distance to a specific point you use as parameters (long + lat).

Comment: If you don't have time to learn the basics of functions in MySQL, then you are better off doing it Python, or any other client language. The MySQL solution has a much higher performance, though. It could be useful in the long run.

Comment: This code doesn't run in PhpMyAmin